# Recharts PieChart - Cell fill with gradient color?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

is it possible to apply gradient fill color on Recharts PieChart like on image below

[image]

I know that we can apply solid color like this

```
  const getCell = () => {
    if (index === COLORS.length) {
      index = 0
    }

    index++
    keyIndex++

    return <Cell key={keyIndex} fill={COLORS[index]} />
  }


        <PieChart width={size} height={size} id={value}>
          <Pie>
            {data.map(() => getCell())}
          </Pie>
        </PieChart>
```

and the result will be the same but without gradient color...

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you